# missing polipo/config file in /usr/local/etc/

Tags: config, polipo

I use brew to install polipo through Mac OS terminal. It seems successfully install, but I can not find the config file and edit it.Can anyone help me figure out the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

- The config file will not be created automatically. You need to get sample config file. Run this command in Terminal:

  ```
  curl -o ~/.polipo https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jech/polipo/master/config.sample
  ```

  and for forbidden URLs:

  ```
  curl -o ~/.polipo-forbidden https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jech/polipo/master/forbidden.sample
  ```

  Then restart polipo to ensure that it will use the config file:

  ```
  launchctl unload /usr/local/opt/polipo/homebrew.mxcl.polipo.plist
  launchctl load /usr/local/opt/polipo/homebrew.mxcl.polipo.plist
  ```

  If it produced `Service is disabled` error, try this command to restart polio:

  ```
  brew services restart polipo
  ```

  Now open this address in your browser:
  http://127.0.0.1:8123/polipo/config

  You should see this line at the top:

  ```
  configFile  /Users/YourUserName/.polipo Configuration file.
  ```

  If so, you need to modify `~/.polipo` to configure your polipo instance.
- There is another way that is not recommended. You can make your config file at `/usr/local/etc/polipo/config` and then create soft link to `/etc/polipo/config` with these commands:

  ```
  mkdir /usr/local/etc/polipo/
  curl -o /usr/local/etc/polipo/config https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jech/polipo/master/config.sample
  sudo ln -sfv /usr/local/etc/polipo/config /etc/polipo/config
  ```

  Then restart polipo and ensure that your config file location is correct. You can modify config file at `/usr/local/etc/polipo/config`.

Answer (score 5):

I also used the brew to install polipo on Mac OS. Same problem as you met.

**In fact, you need create the config file. The fail's path is `~/.polipo`.**

After you start the polipo service(`brew services start polipo`)
Open the link: http://127.0.0.1:8123/polipo/config
[image]

This is my config:
[image]

```
socksParentProxy = "127.0.0.1:1086"
socksParentProxy
socksProxyType = socks5
proxyAddress = "::0"        # both IPv4 and IPv6
proxyPort = 8123
```

Answer (score 1):

**If polipo does not work:**

I wanted to install polipo too, but even with the configuration files provided here, I was getting:

`Error: polipo has been disabled because it is not supported upstream!`

(MacBook Pro M1 chip. My socks proxy was generated with `ssh -D 8000 -C -N myuser@statichost` because of some static IP requirement).

So, I found out that you can also use an npm package to convert socks proxy to http proxy: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-to-socks

```
# install hpts:
npm install -g http-proxy-to-socks

# launch http proxy:
hpts -s 127.0.0.1:8000 -p 8001
# here my socks5 proxy is at 127.0.0.1:8000 and the http proxy is now on port 8001
```

Npm does not support socks5 proxies, for example. So I used hpts to get an http proxy. After, I told npm to use that proxy with:

```
npm config set proxy http://127.0.0.1:8001
npm config set https-proxy http://127.0.0.1:8001
```