# Configure proxy on mac with polipo

Tags: macos, proxy, polipo

I am trying to configure proxy on my mac via polipo. I've installed polipo 1.1.1, but stuck to configure it. The point is that I can not find where the config file is to add proxy host and proxy port. Tried to search for the file via Finder, no results.

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [missing polipo/config file in /usr/local/etc/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749303/missing-polipo-config-file-in-usr-local-etc)

Answer (score 2):

["OS X, Tor, and Polipo"](https://www.cryptomonkeys.com/2015/06/osx-tor-polipo/) you can have a try.