# when i use polipo on my terminal proxy http

Tags: macos, proxy, homebrew, polipo

I use `polipo` on my terminal proxy http request. When I config done, I reload it. It happened an error.

error information on terminal:

[image]

I tried change owner and group of the file, but it does not reload.

```
sudo chgrp staff homebrew.mxcl.polipo.plist
sudo chown baidu homebrew.mxcl.polipo.plist
```

**`/usr/local/Cellar/polipo/1.1.1/homebrew.mxcl.polipo.plist: Path had bad ownership/permissions`**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have installed `polipo` or `homebrew` with root permissions.

Try to set permissions of `/usr/local/Cellar/polipo/1.1.1/` according to your username (my username is `hamidrohani`):

```
$ ls -lah /usr/local/Cellar/polipo/1.1.1/
total 88
drwxr-xr-x  9 hamidrohani  admin   306B Aug  2 02:38 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 hamidrohani  admin   102B May 19 02:50 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 hamidrohani  admin    24K May 15  2014 CHANGES
-rw-r--r--  1 hamidrohani  admin   1.0K May 15  2014 COPYING
-rw-r--r--  1 hamidrohani  admin   369B May 19 02:50 INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
-rw-r--r--  1 hamidrohani  admin   622B May 15  2014 README
drwxr-xr-x  3 hamidrohani  admin   102B May 19 02:50 bin
-rw-r--r--  1 hamidrohani  admin   816B May 19 02:50 homebrew.mxcl.polipo.plist
drwxr-xr-x  5 hamidrohani  admin   170B May 19 02:50 share
```

or try to reinstall `homebrew` and then `polipo` in your current user without any `sudo` prefixes.

Launch agents will be installed in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`. So you can start `polipo` with Homebrew Services:

```
brew services start polipo
```

Homebrew Services will be installed automatically within installation of `homebrew`; Otherwise install it:

```
brew tap homebrew/services
```

After a successful installation, look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37311953/777769) for configurations.